# Law of Iterated Logarithm when the mean does not exist

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables such that $X_1\geq 0$ a.s. and $\mathbb P[X_1>x]\sim x^{-\alpha}$, where $\alpha<1$. This implies that $X_1$ does not have finite mean. Does the following law of iterated logarithm hold?
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n^{\alpha}(\log\log n)^{1-\alpha}}=c,\quad \text{a.s.},
$$
where $c$ is a constant depending on the distribution of $X_1$.
A continuous-time version holds (see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24901237?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)). Also, a special case of the claim exists [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077375916) (Theorem 3) regarding zeros of the simple random walk, in which $\alpha=\frac 12$.

Comment: When $\alpha=3/2$ in $\mathbb P[X_1>x]\sim x^{-\alpha}$ say, then the distribution must fall off like $x^{-5/2}$ at $\infty$, so the mean should lead to the order $x\cdot x^{-5/2}=x^{-3/2}$ and thus the integral is convergent, or?

Comment: @Diger you are right, the condition should be $\alpha <1$ not $\alpha <2$. I will correct it.

Comment: $\alpha \leq 1$ but fair enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it holds. Thanks to Jean Bertoin for telling me the answer, the problem is solved in Theorem 4 of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00563135).